# C# how to make label text invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, label

So I tried to just: 
[image]
 but [image] it is still white.

Why would I want that? 
I want to put image in label and text too but I don't want to text be visible, I can check text content and do some thing orienting by that `if (label1.Text==)`, but `label1.Text` should be invisible so `label1.Text=""` is a bad idea because I want to there be another text.

Comment: Add code and steps to your question. Also add a tag for your UI framrwork. I can't tell iif this is WinForms, WebForms, WPF or ...

Comment: Probably `label1.Visible` or `label1.Visibility`, as said above please provide more details.

Comment: it is windows form app, i have no code yet what should i add?  i just want to have label with invisible text, if i label1.Visible=false; label will be invisible itself

Comment: Then maybe forecolor or something like this

Comment: What about setting the forecolor to be the backcolor?

Comment: If back color is not transparent, then Taw's idea will work. An ideal solution will be based on painting, but it should consider the case which label has assigned with a gif image as well. As a quick and dirty working solution, you can set `label1.Text = "";`. If you need to preserve `Size`, you can set `AutoSize = false;` or if you need auto size, keep the size in a variable, then set auto size to false and set the size to value of that variable. To show the text, set text and then set auto size to true again.

Comment: The question still isn't clear. What project are you working that you have to approach the label control like that?

Answer (score -2):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        x++;
        if (x == 1)
        {
            label1.Text = 1.ToString();
            if (label1.Text == 1.ToString())
                panel2.Visible = true;
            return;
        }
        if (x == 2)
        {
            label2.Text = 1.ToString();
            if (label2.Text == 1.ToString())
                panel4.Visible = true;
            return;

        }
        if (x == 3)
        {
            label3.Text = 1.ToString();
            if (label3.Text == 1.ToString())
                panel6.Visible = true;
            return;
        }




    }
}
}
```

[p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A512.png)
buttion1 click will make panel to be appeared which is on another panel i was trying to do this only with label and background but i guess it is not possible

Comment: i need guess i don't need label at this point anymore and just      if (x == 1){panelname.visible=true}